# Which "Payment Method" setting to use when supporting ACH payments? Authorize.net (eCheck.net)

Tags: payment, authorize.net, echeck.net

Working on supporting ACH payments via eCheck.net. Which "Payment method" should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose anything(its a reference used in Civi) or you can create new one at CiviCRM >> Administer >> CiviContribute >> Payment methods
(/civicrm/admin/options/payment_instrument?reset=1)